# Which is a better way to cast to Boolean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, casting, type-conversion

In JavaScript, which is a more efficient way to cast a value to `Boolean` type,

```
let booleanVal = !!valueToCast;
```

or

```
let booleanVal = Boolean(valueToCast);
```

**PS** I need to typecast in an array tof 1000 elements in api in some use case, so I was wondering which one had the least overhead

Comment: It is opinion based, all are okay

Comment: They're both OK but which one reads better? If I was code golfing I would choose first one, otherwise second one.

Comment: I need to typecast in an array tof 1000 elements in api in some use case, so I was wondering which one had the least overhead

Comment: I would guess `!!` is faster than a function call, but http://jsperf.com can help you confirm it. Having said that, how about `yourArray.map(Boolean)`?

Comment: @JohanP Using the constructor for primitives is never a good idea in JavaScript. Guess what this does: `if(new Boolean(false)) console.log("True!");`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - But OP isn't using `new`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Boolean(value) is not constructor.

Comment: @nnnnnn The point is it can be very deceiving if not used correctly. I strongly recommend not using it but that's my personal opinion

Comment: see `typeof new Boolean(true)` vs `typeof  Boolean(true)` ... and `Boolean` as a function, i.e. as in `.map(Boolean)` is in no way deceiving - nobody thinks Boolean === new Boolean

Comment: @nnnnnn yourArray.map(Boolean) can't be used if I have to cast a particular value from an array of objects. I can do `yourArray.map(x => {x.valToCast = Boolean(x.valToCast)); return x;}` or `yourArray.map(x => {x.valToCast = !!(x.valToCast)); return x;}` but thats the question.

Comment: @JaromandaX "*nobody thinks Boolean === new Boolean*" - You will be surprised how many people think they are. `.map(Boolean)` would be an exception.

Comment: What is input and expected result? What is the issue with the code that you are currently using?

Comment: @guest271314 less of a issue and more of an performance query

Comment: What are the benchmarks of the code that you have tried?

Comment: Performance difference will be absolute minuscule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's already a jsperf that measures the difference between the two at https://jsperf.com/bool-cast-vs-not which shows that in most browsers `Boolean(value)` was significantly slower than `!!value` (though, now in the newer Chrome 59+ it is slightly faster).

However, even at the slowest it was still over 30,000,000 operations a second making it pretty insignificant for your 1000 element dataset.

So choose whichever you like :)